# Creating a session after the correct password has been entered

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making just a very simple password entry form:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text); 

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);  
DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
sda.Fill(dt);

con.Open();  
int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  
con.Close();  

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{  
     Response.Redirect("/login/system.aspx");
}
else
{  
     Label1.Text = "Your password is incorrect!";  
     Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;        
}
```

I need to make a session, providing the row count is greater than 0.

Something like:

```
Session["LoggedInOk"] = "";
```

But, I shouldn't, ever set the TextBox2.Text value (password) into a Session should I?

How can I create a session, so that if they land on the password access page, they are redirected, but without setting the Session to the password.

Can I create just any text for inside the ""?

Then on the password access page something like?:

```
if(Session["LoggedInOk"] == null)
{
    Response.Redirect("/login/default.aspx");
}                   
else
{
    Session["LoggedInOk"] = true; 
}
```

Comment: Using a session for authorization or authentication is not what Session was designed for and would be considered bad practice. Use an existing authentication/authorization framework like ASP.NET Identity or the built in Membership Provider (the later has largely been replaced by the former). These have built in checks and mechanisms to automatically redirect non-authorized requests as well as methods you can call to check for authorization or role checks.

Comment: I have seen Session used in many instances to see if a user is logged in, or to redirect if they are not. Is this considered not appropriate anymore?

Comment: It really is not. You should use an existing solution to check for authorization to the part of the site that the user is trying to navigate to. This will take much more secure then using session to check if the user is authenticated or not.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll look into it.

Comment: The MembershipProvider, (as example), can be configured using the web.config and have the user redirected automatically if they are not authenticated. There is minimal configuration needed to do this and no custom code required (for that action). It can done all in your web.config.

Comment: Perhaps this is just for homework. But in a real application, it's never a good idea to store passwords in the database. Passwords should be one way hashed and salted. Basically retrieving the plaintext version should be very very difficult. Instead, when a user tries to login you should hash their password and see if the hash matches what you have stored for their password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store almost any datatype in a Session. You just need to cast it back to it's original datatype when using it.

```
//string
Session["LoggedInOk"] = "loginOk";
string value = Session["LoggedInOk"].ToString();

//bool
Session["LoggedInOk"] = true;
bool value = Session["LoggedInOk"] as bool;

//class
Book book = new Book();
Session["LoggedInOk"] = book;
Book value = Session["LoggedInOk"] as Book;

//datatable
DataTable table = new DataTable();
Session["LoggedInOk"] = table;
DataTable value = Session["LoggedInOk"] as DataTable;
```

Comment: This is most helpful... Thanks!

Comment: @EhsanSajjad so, should I use an object to see if they are logged in?

Comment: @cmp he means that making a Session out of a DataTable with thousands of rows for example is not a good idea. But I put it as a possibility in my snippet as an example.

Answer (score 2):

Using a session for authorization or authentication checks is not what `Session` was designed for and would be considered bad practice not to mention not secure. Use an existing authentication/authorization framework like ASP.NET Identity or the built in Membership Provider (the later has largely been replaced by the former). These have built in checks and mechanisms to automatically redirect non-authorized requests as well as methods you can call to check for authorization or role checks.

Based on the fact that you are asking about where/if to store a password I am also assuming you are rolling a custom authentication / authorization solution. Again, do not do it and use an existing solution instead. This is more secure than anything you could ever build (myself included for that matter).

[Introduction to ASP.NET Identity](https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)

[How to: Use the ASP.NET Membership Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: this is the actual answer!

Comment: Hi Igor, Ehsan -- What was Session made for?? (If I may ask)

Comment: @cmp - temporary storage on the server for state across requests for a specific browser session. For example: if you wanted to add a wizard that uses post backs to advance the state from the first step to the last you could use a Session. Session is tracked using an id in either a cookie or a query string parameter to ensure the correct state is retrieved/written to and a user does not have to be authenticated to use the session state.

Answer (score 1):

You can set Session when rows returned are greater than 0 which means password and username were correct and row found from table:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) {
     Session["LoggedIn"] = true;  
     Response.Redirect("/login/system.aspx");   

}
```

and in that page you check if it is not null:

```
if(Session["LoggedIn"] == null) {
    Response.Redirect("/login/default.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you that do not store password in session.Once you valid user credentials and confirmed you can set the session that user is valid.

```
Session["LoggedInOk"]=true;//Set the session
```

On password access page you can check session is not null.

```
if(Session["LoggedInOk"] == null)
{
    Response.Redirect("/login/default.aspx");
}
```

Also make sure that once user logout clear the session.

```
Session["LoggedInOk"]=null; //set session null once user click on logout
```